# Get element by ClassName without a string in <span>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get from a piece of HTML code (not mine) the string: `THIS is what I need`

```
<div class="hlFld-Abstract"><h2 id="section-1"><span>Abstract</span></h2><div class="abstractSection abstractInFull"><p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">THIS is what I need</p> </div></div><h2><span>Keywords</span>
```

To do so, I've written the following:

```
document.getElementById("section-1").document.getElementsByClassName("abstractSection abstractInFull")[0].textContent
```

It almost does the job, however it include also `▪ Abstract` , which I do not need. How do I get only the string `THIS is what I need`?

Comment: `document.getElementById("section-1").document.getElementsByClassName ....` *It almost does the job* ... erm, no ... you'd get an error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).document is undefined`

Comment: I don't get any error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `querySelector` for that:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div.abstractSection.abstractInFull p').textContent)
```

```html
<div class="hlFld-Abstract"><h2 id="section-1"><span>Abstract</span></h2><div class="abstractSection abstractInFull"><p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">THIS is what I need</p> </div></div><h2><span>Keywords</span>
```

Comment: This looks great but when I run it in programming language (it uses IE 11), I'm getting also `Abstract`. Why this is the case? The other answer that uses `document.querySelector('p')` is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact html and you run exactly this code?

Comment: Yes, I am. My code is as follows `IE.document.querySelector("div[class='abstractSection abstractInFull']").textContent`. It is very strange that it won't work in different programming language.

Comment: My mistake. It should have been `IE.document.querySelector("div.abstractSection.abstractInFull p").textContent`

Comment: The code doesn't work on my language. The answer by `Hikmat Sijapati` does the trick but it relies only on `p` tag.

Comment: What language you use? You only mentioned javascript

Comment: I use `AutoHotkey`. I didn't mention it because to date every code in JS had worked. This is the first time I have had problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a quick solution in pure Javascript using:**

> querySelector

```js
var mytext = document.querySelector("div[class='abstractSection abstractInFull']");
alert(mytext.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="hlFld-Abstract"><h2 id="section-1"><span>Abstract</span></h2><div class="abstractSection abstractInFull"><p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">THIS is what I need</p></div></div><h2><span>Keywords</span>
```

**Now here's a quick solution with jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myText = $("div[class='abstractSection abstractInFull']").text();
    alert(myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hlFld-Abstract"><h2 id="section-1"><span>Abstract</span></h2><div class="abstractSection abstractInFull"><p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">THIS is what I need</p></div></div><h2><span>Keywords</span>
```

Comment: It is running fine. But when  run it in my programming language (it uses IE 11), I'm getting also `Abstract`. Why this is the case? What is interesting, the other answer that uses document.querySelector('p') is working fine, but I don't think we should rely only on `p`.

Comment: @menteith my answer is NOT relying on "p" at all. I'm using a CSS selector. Did you see my solution??

Comment: I meant that the other solution works fine but it relies solely on `p`. So your solution seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.use `document.querySelector()`.

```js
var text = document.querySelector('p');
alert(text.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="hlFld-Abstract"><h2 id="section-1"><span>Abstract</span></h2><div class="abstractSection abstractInFull"><p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">THIS is what I need</p> </div></div><h2><span>Keywords</span>
```

Comment: Any chance to take into account not only `p` but also  other tags?

Answer (score -2):

Use the Query Selector or Jquery chaining. I see that your html DOM seems to be incorrect.